# Convert WKWebView content to PDF in macOS

Tags: swift, macos, pdf, cocoa, wkwebview

I'm trying to convert the content of a `WKWebView` to a PDF file.

Before `UIWebView` was deprecated it was done this way:

```
webView.loadHTMLString("<h1>HELLO!</h1>", baseURL: nil)    
let pdfData = webView.mainFrame.frameView.documentView.dataWithPDF(inside: webView.mainFrame.frameView.documentView.frame)
let document = PDFDocument(data: pdfData)
```

What I tried now:

```
webView.loadHTMLString("<h1>HELLO!</h1>", baseURL: nil)
let pdfData = self.webViewPDF.webFrame.frameView.documentView.dataWithPDF(inside: self.webViewPDF.webFrame.frameView.documentView.frame)
let document = PDFDocument(data: pdfData)
```

but got the following error instead:

> [WKWebView webFrame]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.
>   [General] An uncaught exception was raised

Problem is `WKWebView` doesn't have `mainFrame` property...

Answer (score 2):

**Update**. The solution bellow works great on **iOS** but I just noticed *now* that you are looking for a **macOS** solution instead. Please let me know if this solution might be of any help at all... sorry for the confusion ;)

---

You can now use the `UIView.viewPrintFormatter()` method (from the `UIView` class) for that:

> Returns a print formatter for the receiving view.
>
> When initiating a print job, you can call this method to obtain an appropriate view print formatter object for your view. You can use the formatter object to configure the page layout options for your view during printing.

For instance:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import PDFKit

extension WKWebView {

    /// Exports a PDF document with this web view current contents.
    /// Only call this function when the web view has **finished** loading.
    func exportAsPDF() -> PDFDocument? {
        guard self.isLoading == false else {
            print("WKWebView still loading!")
            return nil
        }
        let pdfData = createPDFData()
        return PDFDocument(data: pdfData)
    }

    private func createPDFData() -> Data {
        let oldBounds = self.bounds

        var printBounds = self.bounds
        printBounds.size.height = scrollView.contentSize.height
        self.bounds = printBounds

        var printableRect = printBounds
        printableRect.origin = .zero        

        let printRenderer = UIPrintPageRenderer()
        printRenderer.addPrintFormatter(self.viewPrintFormatter(), startingAtPageAt: 0)
        printRenderer.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: UIScreen.main.bounds), forKey: "paperRect")
        printRenderer.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printableRect), forKey: "printableRect")

        self.bounds = oldBounds
        return printRenderer.generatePDFData()
    }
}
```

and add the following helper method to `UIPrintPageRenderer` as well:

```
extension UIPrintPageRenderer {

    func generatePDFData() -> Data {
        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, self.paperRect, nil)
        self.prepare(forDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, self.numberOfPages))
        let printRect = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()

        for pdfPage in 0..<self.numberOfPages {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
            self.drawPage(at: pdfPage, in: printRect)
        }

        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        return pdfData as Data
    }
}
```

Finally, you can now save a PDF using the `exportAsPDF()` API defined above:

```
let webView: WKWebView = ...

let pdfDocument = webView.exportAsPDF()!

let docsDir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let pdfFile = docsDir.appendingPathComponent("WebViewPDF.pdf")

try! pdfDocument.write(to: pdfFile)
```

Comment: thanks but I don't know the equivalent for UIPrintPageRenderer in cocoa